# Convert UNION ALLs to JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, union

Is there a way to convert `UNION ALL` to `JOIN` and still get similar output.

Here is an example query to illustrate:

```
DECLARE @customerIdentifierId BIGINT 
SET @customerIdentifierId = 2

SELECT  1 AS Tag, NULL AS Parent, cust.CustomerId AS CustomerId, 
        NULL AS CustomerIdentifierId, NULL AS OrderDetailId
FROM    Customer.CustomerIdentifier custIdent            
        JOIN Customer.Customer cust
            ON cust.CurrentCustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
        JOIN detail.OrderDetail detail
            ON detail.CustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
WHERE   custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId = @customerIdentifierId

UNION ALL

SELECT  2, 1, NULL, custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId, null
FROM    Customer.CustomerIdentifier custIdent            
        JOIN Customer.Customer cust
            ON cust.CurrentCustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
        JOIN detail.OrderDetail detail
            ON detail.CustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
WHERE   custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId = @customerIdentifierId

UNION ALL

SELECT  3, 1, NULL, null, detail.OrderDetailId
FROM    Customer.CustomerIdentifier custIdent            
        JOIN Customer.Customer cust
            ON cust.CurrentCustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
        JOIN detail.OrderDetail detail
            ON detail.CustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
WHERE   custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId = @customerIdentifierId
```

It is not so important that the nulls have null in them, but I need the separate rows that the union gives.

I tried doing a `CROSS JOIN`, and it did not work out.  I am hoping there is some other `SQL` trick that can do it (`CROSS APPLY`?)

In case it matters, my end goal is to get this to work in an indexed (materialized) view in `SQL Server`.

This is the output I am looking for:

```
Tag         Parent      CustomerId           CustomerIdentifierId OrderDetailId
----------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           NULL        4                    NULL                 NULL
1           NULL        4                    NULL                 NULL
1           NULL        4                    NULL                 NULL
1           NULL        4                    NULL                 NULL
1           NULL        4                    NULL                 NULL
2           1           NULL                 2                    NULL
2           1           NULL                 2                    NULL
2           1           NULL                 2                    NULL
2           1           NULL                 2                    NULL
2           1           NULL                 2                    NULL
3           2           NULL                 NULL                 2
3           2           NULL                 NULL                 14
3           2           NULL                 NULL                 26
3           2           NULL                 NULL                 38
3           2           NULL                 NULL                 50
```

The Tables are a parent to many children relationship:

1 Customer            to     Many CustomerIdentifiers
1 CustomerIdentifier  to     Many OrderDetails

(It makes a tree)

Here is a [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Vaccano/3d66a6f97e470ab104ca/raw/d843952d5635fb184d7c6c64599a5b26d22afdff/gistfile1.txt) to the sql needed to create the tables to make my above query work:

Comment: Can you put the table structures and the expected output in a table format?

Comment: @Kangkan I added them.

Comment: "Is there a way to convert UNION ALL to JOIN"? Yes this is easy. Just full outer join on 1=0 and use a case expression to return the correct column source. But you still won't be able to use that in an indexed view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never done a indexed view but you could rewrite the query:

```
INSERT INTO @xmlDataTable(Tag, Parent, [Customer!1!CustomerId],
            [CustomerIdentifier!2!CustomerIdentifierId], [OrderDetail!3!OrderDetailId])

SELECT  rows.*
FROM    Customer.CustomerIdentifier custIdent            
        JOIN Customer.Customer cust
            ON cust.CurrentCustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
        JOIN [order].OrderDetail detail
            ON detail.CustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
WHERE   detail.CustomerIdentifierId = @customerIdentifierId
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT 1, NULL, cust.CustomerId, NULL, null
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  2, 1, NULL, custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId, null
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  3, 1, NULL, null, detail.OrderDetailId
) rows
```

Comment: Still can't use this in a Indexed View.  But I like the look of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use variables so that you can get the whole bit done with one select and one insert. For example:

```
DECLARE 
@CustomerId INT,
@OrderDetailId INT;

SELECT
    @CustomerID = cust.CustomerId,
    @OrderDetailID = detail.OrderDetailId
FROM    
    Customer.CustomerIdentifier custIdent
    INNER JOIN Customer.Customer cust ON cust.CurrentCustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
    INNER JOIN [order].OrderDetail detail ON detail.CustomerIdentifierId = custIdent.CustomerIdentifierId
WHERE
    detail.CustomerIdentifierId = @customerIdentifierId;

INSERT INTO @xmlDataTable(Tag, Parent, [Customer!1!CustomerId],
            [CustomerIdentifier!2!CustomerIdentifierId], [OrderDetail!3!OrderDetailId])
VALUES
(1, NULL, @CustomerID , NULL, NULL),
(2, 1, NULL, @customerIdentifierId, NULL),
(3, 1, NULL, null, @OrderDetailID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pseudo code of a hacky way you could do it:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.Col1, t2.Col1, tN.Col1) AS Col1
, COALESCE(t1.Col2, t2.Col2, tN.Col2) AS Col2
, COALESCE(t1.ColN, t2.ColN, tN.ColN) AS ColN
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON 1=0
FULL OUTER JOIN tN ON 1=0
```

I haven't explored whether this would violate the requirements of an indexed view, but it is a way you can duplicate the results of a UNION ALL using JOINs.